# in Rshiny, why does the javascript function setInputValue make observeEvent run twice?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm making an Rmarkdown `html_document` shiny app which has a `selectInput`.

I have made a minimal code example to reproduce the issue I have:

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
selectInput("selectYear", label = "Year", choices = c("All", 2006:2021), selected = "All")

observeEvent(input$selectYear, {
  message("input$selectYear = ", input$selectYear) 
  throttle(
    {
      updateSelectInput(session, "selectYear", choices = c("All", 2006:2021), selected = input$selectYear)
    },
    100000
  )
})
```<!-- -->
````

(you can remove the `<!-- -->`, that's only for code formatting here in SO. EDIT: To run this, I store it in a Rmd file and execute with `rmarkdown::run("filename.Rmd", shiny_args = list(port = 5050, host = "0.0.0.0"))`)

This minimal app looks like this:
[image: screenshot showing a dropdown select with All selected]

I have also build several charts (striped down in this minimal example) and wanted to trigger a change of `selectYear` with JavaScript (for example on the event of clicking a bar in chart).  Here is a snippet to reproduce the issue:

```
Shiny.setInputValue('selectYear', 2015);
```

The issue I have is that this javascript triggers twice the `observeEvent`, we can see in the log:

> input$selectYear = 2015
> input$selectYear = 2015

I know it is not an issue in this example because it's too fast too notice, but when you have more code with data processing and many things happening in the app, this becomes noticeable and my chart flickers twice with whole seconds apart which is unacceptable.

Note that this double trigger doesnt happen if you use the html dropdown.

The reason to have the `observeEvent` is that if I don't have it, then dropdown doesn't update visually with the new value of `2015`, the value only changes in the background but the dom doesnt change.
Therefore I have setup the `observeEvent` with `updateSelectInput` to change the display of the dropdown as well. I don't see any other solution for that, but if you have that could also solve my issue here.

---

TRIED AND FAILED:

- [debounce / throttle](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/shiny/html/debounce.html) (as you can see in the snippet above)
- sending a flag from JS to prevent double trigger:

  `Shiny.setInputValue('updateFromJS', true);`

```
checkboxInput("updateFromJS", "updateFromJS", TRUE)
observeEvent(input$selectYear, {
  message("input$selectYear = ", input$selectYear, " input$updateFromJS = ", input$updateFromJS)
  if (input$updateFromJS == TRUE) {
    message("updating...")
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "updateFromJS", "updateFromJS", FALSE) ## i.e. input$updateFromJS <- FALSE
    updateSelectInput(session, "selectYear", choices = c("All", 2006:2021), selected = input$selectYear)
  }
})
```

I also wonder why does it run twice and not in an infinite loop.
And how come `throttle` and `debounce` do not work?

Comment: because the `updateSelectInput` triggers the observer.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent then why isn't it making an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `Shiny.setInputValue("selectYear", 2015)`, then `input$selectYear` takes the value `2015`, a *number*. Then the `updateSelectInput` sets `input$selectYear` to the value `"2015"`, a *character string*. There's no infinite loop because nothing changes `input$selectYear` after that.

To see that:

```r
  observeEvent(input$selectYear, {
    message("input$selectYear = ", mode(input$selectYear)) 
    updateSelectInput(session, "selectYear", selected = input$selectYear)
  })
```